# Different Documents with the same URI in Marklogic

Tags: xml, database, xquery, marklogic

In the Marklogic XML DB that I am working on, there are two different documents that have the same URI. Is legal to have the same URI for different XML docs in Marklogic DB ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MarkLogic documents are identified by their URI. You should not have different documents with same URI but it can happen. Take a look at this link https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/22/0/handling-xdmp-dbdupuri-errors . It has suggestions on how to resolve the issue

Comment: This thread on MarkLogic Dev mailinglist might be of interest as well: http://marklogic.markmail.org/thread/zet3ncxahes2h7il

Answer (score 1):

You can use same URI there is no violation as such. Since your requirement asks for same URI, you can give each document a different collection and hence you will be able to fetch/query your database accordingly.

Comment: You cannot save two different documents at the same uri, and distinguish them by collections. Collections are metadata to a document in MarkLogic, not buckets for storage.